# How to adjust android stuidio guide line on coding page?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

How can i adjust that white line, i want my code cross that line when i do reformat code (cmd + shift + L) my codes adjusting itself which stays on left side of that white line. I want to push that line to right side. Is anyone know how to do that?

[image: White line]

Comment: search what is this line, why it is there. you probably should never change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I answer your question:

This line represents the margin of A4 paper, which is useful mainly in one case:
imagine if that line did not exist and your workmate had a 5120 x 1440 monitor, his/hers "one-liners" would NOT fit into one line on your screen (and if you had line wrapping turned off, you would have to scroll horizontally to see what a line of code does, it would be really annoying!), so if you want to save your workmates or anybody reading your code on a smaller monitor, you should not disable that line

And now the answer to your question:

go to:

Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap guide

(or File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show hard wrap and visual guides)